# Debug on remote JupyterLab Server with IDE (Pycharm)

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, remote-debugging

Does someone know, how to connect to remote JupyterLab Server and debug Jupyter Notebooks?

Context: In my company we have GPU-Servers, on which JuypterLab is installed inside of docker-containers.
Due to security reasons, we can connect to the JupyterLab frontend (with given url), but we cannot create containers ourselves etc...

In Pycharm I can connect to this url (like  `http://<ip>:<port>/lab?token=<token>`) and run my notebook cells.
But when I try to debug, I get the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydev_jupyter_utils'
```

On the other side, on the JupyterLab frontend, there is an built-in option to debug cells, and it works out of the box.
So from the technical aspect, it should also be possible to debug remotely I guess?

Does someone has experience on how to do this, or maybe some hints on what to google?

I have not found anything useful in the internet so far. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

according to https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/whatsnew/, it's the new feature in pycharm professional 2023.1 version

but there is one thing to note: you must use the third way **Connect to Jupyter server using URL** in https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-jupyter-notebook.html#remote to connect the remote jupyter server. the debugger feature is only for this way